# Showing and positioning a UISwitch, or any UIView in an Adobe Native Extension for iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiswitch, air-native-extension

I am writing a simple Adobe native extension for iOS.

All it does it show a UISwitch.

However, when I try to setFrame on that UISwitch (or any UIView in this piece of code), or even access the frame of the UISwitch, the app segfaults with a bad memory access crash.
The UISwitch itself is NOT nil, because calling **setOn** on it works, and the UISwitch does show up on the screen if I don't try to call setFrame on it, or set its center, or position it in any way.

Here's the code. The function in question is the first one: **showSwitch()**

```
#import "FlashRuntimeExtensions.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

FREObject showSwitch(FREContext context, 
                     void* functionData, 
                     uint32_t argc, 
                     FREObject argv[])
{
    int32_t isOn;
    FREGetObjectAsInt32(argv[0], &isOn);

    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    UIWindow* window = [delegate window];

    // The following will segfault
    // UISwitch* switchControl = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0)];

    // This works fine.
    UISwitch* switchControl = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] retain];

    // This will segfault as well
    // [switchControl setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, switchControl.frame.size.width, switchControl.frame.size.height)];

    [switchControl setOn:(isOn == 1)]; // switchControl is not nil, because this works.
    [window addSubview:switchControl];

    return NULL;
}

void ContextFinalizer(FREContext context)
{
    return;
}

void ContextInitializer(void* extensionData, 
                        const uint8_t* contextType, 
                        FREContext context, 
                        uint32_t* numFunctionsToTest, 
                        const FRENamedFunction** functionsToSet)
{
    *numFunctionsToTest = 1;

    FRENamedFunction* function = (FRENamedFunction*)malloc(sizeof(FRENamedFunction)*1);
    function[0].name = (const uint8_t*)"showSwitch";
    function[0].functionData = NULL;
    function[0].function = &showSwitch;

    *functionsToSet = function;

}

void ExtensionInitializer(void** extensionDataToSet, 
                          FREContextInitializer* contextInitializerToSet, 
                          FREContextFinalizer* contextFinalizerToSet)
{
    *extensionDataToSet = NULL;
    *contextInitializerToSet = &ContextInitializer;
    *contextFinalizerToSet = &ContextFinalizer;
}

void ExtensionFinalizer(void* extensionData)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to add a view to the window, and after search and test a lot I found this solution, that may help anybody with the same problem.

Add your subview this way:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].view addSubview: switchControl];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the AppDelegate (don't forget to include the .h file). Then you add your switch to the window or to the rootViewController.

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.window addSubview:switchControl];
```